# How to suppress extra django-created HTML?

Tags: html, django

I want to create an "clean" HTML document from a django view that the user can save and import into excel. "Clean" in this case means it only contains tags specified in my template without any extraneous tags being added by the back-end.
Some part of Django or a Django extension is adding extra unwanted HTML to my final rendered pages. How can I suppress this? For example if I pass the "blank" html template shown below to render:

```
    return render(request, 'blank.html')
```

the output contains extra divs and a hidden textarea at the end of the body tag (out put also shown below).

I disabled django-debug-toolbar to get rid of most of the extra, back-end html that was being added to my files, however I can't seem to get rid of this last set of extra tags.

File: blank.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Output html saved by chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0028)http://localhost:57362/test/ -->
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="background: rgba(135, 206, 235, 0.7); border: 3px double; box-sizing: content-box; display: none; pointer-events: none; position: absolute; z-index: 32767;"></div>
    <textarea style="border-radius: 0px; margin: 0px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: -32767px; z-index: 32767;"></textarea>
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; visibility: hidden;">
        <tr>
             <td style="border: 1px solid; padding: 0px; width: 1px;"></td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured this out.

The extra tags were be inserted by the HttpResponse() method. Changing the content type of this resulted in a clean html file being downloaded by the client browser.

Old code in view.py:

```
return render(request, 'blank.html')
```

New Code in view.py:

```
    response =  render(request, 'blank.html', content_type='text/html')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.html"'
    return response
```